# Eliminate negative elements in set (Python)

Tags: python, set

```
X1 = set([-2,6,36,31,33,11,4])
X = set([--])
```

What would I need to write inside the X set in order to eliminate -2 from X1? Something that would work like this: `X = set([x for only x<0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension:

```
X = {v for v in X1 if v >= 0}
```

This produces a new set by looping over `X1` and including all values that are 0 or greater:

```
>>> X1 = set([-2, 6, 36, 31, 33, 11, 4])
>>> {v for v in X1 if v >= 0}
set([33, 36, 6, 11, 4, 31])
```

See the [Python tutorial on sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) for a pointer on set comprehensions, which are closely related to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps) and [dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).